# MySQL 8 no longer starts because of lower_case_table_names

Tags: macos, mysql, docker

I have a docker mysql 8 container that I have been using for a couple years. Suddenly out of no where it won't start with these errors:

```
[Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
...
[ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('2') and data dictionary ('0').
[ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

My other container running mysql 5.7 is still working as expected.

I am running this docker image on MacOS 10.14.6. It happened after either a crash or upgrade of docker desktop, not sure which one caused it. I have searched all over the internet for a fix but have come up empty handed. All the solutions I found haven't worked.

This is my docker-compose entry.

```
 "mysql-8.0":
    container_name: "mysql-8.0"
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    networks:
      - matrix
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3380:3306
    volumes:
      - "./db-8.0:/var/lib/mysql:cached"
      - "./db-8.0/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=******
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
```

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this? Like I said before this has been working for years up until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was caused by the latest version of Docker 2.3.5.0. This update is what caused the problem:

> Docker Desktop now uses gRPC-FUSE for file sharing by default. This
> has much faster file sharing and uses much less CPU than osxfs,
> especially when there are lots of file events on the host.

Once I downgraded to the previous versions of docker that I had installed (2.3.1.0) everything went back to normal. I'll have to backup all databases before I upgrade again.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `lower_case_table_names` should be set at the time of initialization. Try setting it while you run your docker, so that it will be picked during initialization,

```
"mysql-8.0":
    container_name: "mysql-8.0"
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    networks:
      - matrix
    command: --lower_case_table_names=2
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3380:3306
    volumes:
      - "./db-8.0:/var/lib/mysql:cached"
      - "./db-8.0/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=******
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
```

Make sure to keep your authentication plugin command in docker compose and try toggling between `0|1|2` as value for `lower_case_table_names`

Comment: No amount of changing those flags fixed the problem for me. I ended up downgrading back to what I had installed previously and it worked without modification. Thanks for taking the time. Normally your suggestion would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute this command

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/lowercase-table-names select Enabled"
```

and add this command to your docker-compose file: '

```
command: --lower_case_table_names=1
```

before building your container.